# How to reduce image creation time of an image php GD

Tags: php, image, imagick

Using GD functions changing color of an image. Due to several ***iteration*** it taking large time to create. As mention below scripts pink(255,0,255) and near about color replace with other dynamic colors. Script output is correct but as mention it taking large time to create a output image.

> Is it possible to reduce creation time of an image with color
>   changeable functionality or can we change any section of code?

```
 function changeImageColor($oldColorTriplet, $newColorTriplet, $hueError = 0.4){
        if (!$this->isImageCreated())
            return false;

        $oldColorHSL = $this->RGBtoHSL($oldColorTriplet[0], $oldColorTriplet[1], $oldColorTriplet[2]);
        $newColorHSL = $this->RGBtoHSL($newColorTriplet[0], $newColorTriplet[1], $newColorTriplet[2]);
        $cx = $this->width();
        $cy = $this->height();
        for ($x = 0; $x < $cx; $x++) {
            for ($y = 0; $y < $cy; $y++) {
                $pixel = imagecolorsforindex($this->handle, imagecolorat($this->handle, $x, $y));

                $currentColorHSL = $this->RGBtoHSL($pixel['red'], $pixel['green'], $pixel['blue']);

                if (($currentColorHSL[0] >= $oldColorHSL[0] - $hueError)
                    && ($oldColorHSL[0] + $hueError >= $currentColorHSL[0])) {
                    //$color = $this->HSLtoRGB($newColorHSL[0], $newColorHSL[1], $currentColorHSL[2]);
                    $color = $newColorTriplet;
                    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->handle, $color[0], $color[1], $color[2], $pixel['alpha']);
                    imagesetpixel($this->handle, $x, $y, $color);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

function RGBtoHSL( $r, $g, $b ){
        $r /= 255;
        $g /= 255;
        $b /= 255;
        $max = max( $r, $g, $b );
        $min = min( $r, $g, $b );
        $l = ( $max + $min ) / 2;
        $d = $max - $min;
        if( $d == 0 ){
            $h = $s = 0;
        } else {
            $s = $d / ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) );
            switch( $max ){
                case $r:
                    $h = 60 * fmod( ( ( $g - $b ) / $d ), 6 );
                    if ($b > $g) {
                        $h += 360;
                    }
                    break;
                case $g:
                    $h = 60 * ( ( $b - $r ) / $d + 2 );
                    break;
                case $b:
                    $h = 60 * ( ( $r - $g ) / $d + 4 );
                    break;
            }
        }
        return array( round( $h, 2 ), round( $s, 2 ), round( $l, 2 ) );
    }

    function HSLtoRGB( $h, $s, $l ){
        $c = ( 1 - abs( 2 * $l - 1 ) ) * $s;
        $x = $c * ( 1 - abs( fmod( ( $h / 60 ), 2 ) - 1 ) );
        $m = $l - ( $c / 2 );
        if ( $h < 60 ) {
            $r = $c;
            $g = $x;
            $b = 0;
        } else if ( $h < 120 ) {
            $r = $x;
            $g = $c;
            $b = 0;
        } else if ( $h < 180 ) {
            $r = 0;
            $g = $c;
            $b = $x;
        } else if ( $h < 240 ) {
            $r = 0;
            $g = $x;
            $b = $c;
        } else if ( $h < 300 ) {
            $r = $x;
            $g = 0;
            $b = $c;
        } else {
            $r = $c;
            $g = 0;
            $b = $x;
        }
        $r = ( $r + $m ) * 255;
        $g = ( $g + $m ) * 255;
        $b = ( $b + $m  ) * 255;
        return array( floor( $r ), floor( $g ), floor( $b ) );
    }
```

Comment: You could try to use the fxImage routine http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/fxImage however that is not guaranteed to be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I got some other way to reduce image creation time :

- While uploading an image I get all pixels that are near to rgb(255,0,255) and store in DB.
- Than call only those pixel that to
  replace colour and implemented above code at only these positions.
- **Means suppose a image, have 10,000 pixel 1000 pixels are
  rgb(255,0,255) than I save this 1000 pixel positions and while apply
  colour I send only these 1000 pixel to change the colour.**

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on PHP+GD but it looks to me like you are taking all pixels within a band either side of some HSL colour and replacing them by a solid colour - if so, you can do that pretty quickly with ImageMagick in PHP. I'll try and show the concept at the command line and you can then benchmark it as ImageMagick is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

First let's make a gradient image, called `swatch.png`, for testing, that includes some pink colour:

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient:blue-pink gradient:pink-blue -rotate -90 +append swatch.png
```

[image]

Now, let's see what ImageMagick thinks `pink` looks like in HSL coordinates:

```
convert xc:pink -depth 8 -colorspace hsl txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,hsl
0,0: (63628,65535,57440)  #F8FFE0  hsl(349.524,100%,87.6478%)
```

So, that makes the Hue component 63628/65535, or 349.524/360 or 97%

Now, if we take the swatch and copy it, then go into the copy and convert to HSL colourspace, separate out the H,S &L channels, and delete the Saturation and Lightness, we will just have the Hue channel present. If we now make everything less than 96% turn black and then make blacks transparent and everything more than 98% turn white and then make whites transparent we will only have any opacity in our image where the hue is between 96-98%, i.e. around our pink colour. If we now fill the image with lime green and overlay it on top of the original, we will see we have replaced the pink hues with lime green.

```
convert swatch.png                                 \
  \( +clone -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 1,2  \
     -black-threshold 96% -transparent black       \
     -white-threshold 98% -transparent white       \
     -fill lime -colorize 100%                     \
  \) -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

If we widen the lower-end tolerance to 90% on the Hue:

```
convert swatch.png \( +clone -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 1,2 -black-threshold 90% -transparent black -white-threshold 98% -transparent white -fill lime -colorize 100% \) -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

And if we narrow the upper-end tolerance on the Hue:

```
convert swatch.png \( +clone -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 1,2 -black-threshold 96.0% -transparent black -white-threshold 97.0% -transparent white -fill red -colorize 100% \) -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

There are other ways of doing this with ImageMagick, but this should give you an idea and you can test it out at the command line before going to the effort of implementing any PHP.